# Run a Swift UI Page from Flutter AppDelegate.swift file

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I want to run a custom Swift UI page in my flutter application. I am trying to call ios platform specific code using method channel. My target is when i call a method using method channel i will present the Swift UI view in front of user.

My `AppDelegate.swift` file is below:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let batteryChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "yourpackageName/channelName",
                                                  binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        batteryChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            
            if call.method == "showPage"{
                //run a swift ui view here
            }
        })
        
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

And my custom Swift UI file is below:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct CustomPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct CustomPage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomPage()
    }
}
```

Is there any way i can achieve this?